# Self hosted OWIN SignalR in Azure WebApps

Tags: asp.net, azure, f#, signalr, owin

I am deploying quite a few F# apps and services using the HttpPlatformHandler trick, but am trying to get up and running with a signalr server using OWIN and F# and nothing is 'just working'.

I have a very simple OWIN and Signalr server that works just fine locally, but when I try to push it to azure nothing seems to be working (well everything is hanging).

```ml
[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =     

    // Code omitted for brevity (works in suave.io)
    let localPort = getEnvironmentVariableOrDefault "my-port" "8085"

    let startup (a:IAppBuilder) =            
        a.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll) |> ignore
        a.MapSignalR() |> ignore

    let hostUrl = sprintf "http://localhost:%s" localPort
    use app = WebApp.Start(hostUrl, startup)

    Console.WriteLine("Server running on "+ hostUrl)
    Console.ReadLine() |> ignore
```

the web.config is very simple

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
        <remove name="httpplatformhandler" />
        <add name="httpplatformhandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="httpPlatformHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <httpPlatform stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile="my.log" startupTimeLimit="20" processPath="%HOME%\site\wwwroot\MyOwnSelfHost.exe">
        <environmentVariables>
          <environmentVariable name="my-port" value="%HTTP_PLATFORM_PORT%"/> 
        </environmentVariables>            
    </httpPlatform>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

What am I doing wrong here, is there a different method to using HttpPlatformHandler?

Would love to get some help in getting this running! If the only option is switching to an IIS enabled web project, then that is the only option, but would like to know for sure.

Edit: Exception log

```
Application: MyOwinSelfHost.exe Framework Version: v4.0.30319 
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception. 
Exception Info: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException 
Stack: 
at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(System.Object, System.Object[], System.Signature, Boolean) 
at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(System.Object, System.Object[], System.Object[]) 
at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(System.Object, System.Reflection.BindingFlags, System.Reflection.Binder, System.Object[], System.Globalization.CultureInfo) 
at Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.ServerFactory.ServerFactoryAdapter.Create(Owin.IAppBuilder) 
at Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.Engine.HostingEngine.StartServer(Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.Engine.StartContext) 
at Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.Engine.HostingEngine.Start(Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.Engine.StartContext) 
at Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.WebApp.StartImplementation(System.IServiceProvider, Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.StartOptions, System.Action`1) 
at MyOwinSelfHost.Starter.main(System.String[])
```

And the HttpPlatformHandler error

```
Process '4200' failed to start. Port = 5332, Error Code = '-2147023829'.
```

Comment: Did you ever get this working? I have a similar issue with my self hosted F# web application.

Comment: Not for signalr, I ended up just hosting a bare bone C# app, but not a self host, but an IIS OWIN host and having that call out to the F# code. So all the Hubs are implemented in C#, couldn't get it working in F# and didn't have the time to invest in a lot of investigation. I'd like to revisit this though.

Comment: Ok. I ditched the selfhosted part and created a IIS-hosted version of my app instead. Still not trivial though :(